# Break condition on serial port

Tags: windows, embedded, serial-port, hardware-interface, uart

I am setting up a communication with several devices via a COM port.

For the sake of presence check, I would like to implement that a present device can set a so-called BREAK condition on its UART TX. (A break condition is a condition where the sender sets its TX to low for more than 8 bits.)

But how can I detect this condition on the PC side under Windows? I have found some functions to set a break condition, or to send a timed break, but not for detecting one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A break is an interrupt kind of event, it should only be used to reset communication in progress.  So you'll get it from WaitCommEvent, EV_BREAK event bit.

Favor the handshake signals for a "presence" test.  GetCommModemStatus, MS_DSR_ON tells you that the device is powered-up, MS_CTS_ON tells you that it is willing to receive data.

Comment: Due to lack of wires, I neither have DSR nor CTS... But the EV_BREAK stuff might help me, thanks!